# Should be simple (but it isn't): Javascript snippet inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, animation

I have coded in PHP and JS for a while, but I don't do it often, and so I've been snagged by something that should be simple, but it's giving me fits. And none of the answers I've found here have solved the problem.

I have JS slideshow code that is inserted into a WordPress page when multiple images named [pagename]1,2,3...png are present in the images folder.  I've struggled to get the code to read the folder, and now it does.  But the JS slideshow is not working on the "Menu" page, while the exact same code is working on the "Home" page.  The only difference between the two is that the Menu code tests whether images are present in the images folder.  (They are.)

This first part of the code is, I feel certain, correct.  The second piece of code is where the issue is.  Why is the JS not starting my slideshow?  It should. The code reads properly on the page.

```
<?php
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$x = 1;
$poname = $post->post_name;
if ($dir = opendir('/home/rowlandwilliams/public_html/lepeep/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/images')) {
    $images = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $images[] = $file; 
            asort($images);
        }
    }
closedir($dir);
}
```

And this is where I think the problem is:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
    $subimg = substr($image, 0, -5);
    if ($subimg == $poname) { 
        if ($x == 1) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            function cycleImages(container) {
                var $active = container.find('.active');
                var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : container.find('img:first');
                $next.css('z-index',2);
                $active.fadeOut(1500,function() { 
                    $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
                    $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
                });
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setInterval(function(){cycleImages($('#page-cycler'))}, 2000);
                })
            }
            </script>"; ?>

            <div class="cycler" id="page-cycler">   
                <?php $actstat = 'class="active"'; ?>
                <?php $x++; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php $actstat = ''; ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <img <?php echo $actstat; ?> src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo $image; ?>">
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
            </div><!-- #page-cycler -->
```

http://rowlandwilliams.com/lepeep/menu/

Comment: Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: This code is a mess.  Don't echo your JavaScript with PHP like that.  Maintain it separately.  Also make sure you're escaping any data you do need to pass with `json_encode()`.  And,  why define that function in a loop anyway?  Don't do that!  It's crazy and completely unnecessary.

Comment: I try to avoid JS at all costs.  That's why this looks so bad: Inexperience.  

What is the simplest means of fixing this? The JS works perfectly where I'm not having to check the folder for images.

Comment: Just guessing a bit, but replace  'bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');' with get_stylesheet_directory_uri() in the js..

Answer (score 2):

This is where your problem is:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            function cycleImages(container) {
                var $active = container.find('.active');
                var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : container.find('img:first');
                $next.css('z-index',2);
                $active.fadeOut(1500,function() { 
                    $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
                    $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
                });
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setInterval(function(){cycleImages($('#page-cycler'))}, 2000);
                })
            }
            </script>";
```

When you use `"` to echo with, php will parse all `$var`...

So the variable `$active`and `$next` is being echoed from php, which doesn't look like it's set anywhere in your code. The solution would either be to change variable names from `$active` to `active` or to use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`

Comment: I did not initially have echo there.  I ended PHP before the script and restarted it after.  That did not work, either.

Comment: So you're telling me that I need to initialize the variables used in the JS somewhere before the PHP begins?  If I do that, will those values carry over to this script?

Answer (score 0):

Using single quotes (') will tell PHP not to parse any variables inside the echo, while using double quotes (") will.

Try using ' quotes, and replace any ' quotes inside the JS with " quotes.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            function cycleImages(container) {
                var $active = container.find(".active");
                var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : container.find("img:first");
                $next.css("z-index",2);
                $active.fadeOut(1500,function() { 
                    $active.css("z-index",1).show().removeClass("active");
                    $next.css("z-index",3).addClass("active");
                });
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setInterval(function(){cycleImages($("#page-cycler"))}, 2000);
                })
            }
            </script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mess, I have rewrite your code for more clean, maybe. Since you there is no php code inside your javascript, don't try to use echo it will make your code even mess and as @Arian mentioned, $active and $next will be work as php variable.

```
foreach($images as $image):
    $subimg = substr($image, 0, -5);
    if ($subimg == $poname): 
        if ($x == 1): ?>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
            function cycleImages(container) {
                var $active = container.find('.active');
                var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : container.find('img:first');
                $next.css('z-index',2);
                $active.fadeOut(1500,function() { 
                    $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
                    $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
                });
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setInterval(function(){cycleImages($('#page-cycler'))}, 2000);
                })
            }
            </script>

            <div class="cycler" id="page-cycler">   

        <?php 
              $actstat = 'class="active"'; 
              $x++; 
        else:
             $actstat = '';
        endif; ?>

        <img <?= $actstat; ?> src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/<?= $image; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
             </div><!-- #page-cycler -->
```